# Grails fetch:"join" confusion

Tags: hibernate, grails, join

Recently I upgraded from Grails 1.3.9 to 2.2.4 and noticed some inconsistent behaviour with a fetch:"join" mapping. I created a simple grails project to demonstrate the problem.

Report Domain:

```
class Report {

    String name

    static hasMany = [variables:Variable]

    static mapping = {
        variables cascade: "all-delete-orphan", fetch: "join"
    }
}
```

Variable Domain:

```
class Variable {

    String name

    static belongsTo = [parent:Report]
}
```

Running the following script in Grails console in 2.2.4:

```
if(!Report.findByName("Test")){ 
Report report = new Report(name:"Test")
Variable var1 = new Variable(name:"var")
Variable var2 = new Variable(name:"var2")
report.addToVariables(var1)
report.addToVariables(var2)
report.save(flush:true)
}

def report2 = Report.findByName("Test")
println report2.variables

def report3 = Report.findAllByName("Test")
println report3.get(0).variables

def report4 = Report.findByName("Test",[fetch:[variables:"eager"]])
println report4.variables
```

Gives the following output:

On the first run of the script:

```
[findbytest.Variable : 1, findbytest.Variable : 2]
[findbytest.Variable : 1, findbytest.Variable : 2]
[findbytest.Variable : 1, findbytest.Variable : 2]
```

On the second and all subsequent runs of the script:

```
[findbytest.Variable : 1]
[findbytest.Variable : 1]
[findbytest.Variable : 1]
```

Removing the fetch:"join" and rerunning the script gives the following output every time:

```
[findbytest.Variable : 1, findbytest.Variable : 2]
[findbytest.Variable : 1, findbytest.Variable : 2]
[findbytest.Variable : 1, findbytest.Variable : 2]
```

Running the same script on 1.3.9 with and without the fetch:"join" gives the following output every time:

```
[findbytest.Variable : 1, findbytest.Variable : 2]
[findbytest.Variable : 1, findbytest.Variable : 2]
[findbytest.Variable : 1, findbytest.Variable : 2]
```

Any help or direction is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The provided answer could be the cause but you are not using criteria here which is the only difference, also why did it change between 1.3.9 and 2.2.4, shouldn't they both have the bug?  It might be worth checking what sql is generated (logSql).  Also make the same project in 2.4.2 and see if the issue is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may have to do with this bug: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9829

This practically means that with any kind of Criteria based query, you cannot use fetch-joins.

You will need to use direct HQL for this kind of optimized queries.

If your problem traces back to the above bug, please comment on the bug report, maybe its importance grows sufficiently to warrant action (I think this is a big-enough problem to even trigger a patched version of Hibernate3 by someone).